# Quantifiers and Negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

What is the negation of the following statement?

∀ ∃! (((,)∨~(,))⟷(,))

I have a problem to get the negation of ∃! (unique existential quantification) in such that problem.

Comment: You have already asked it a couple of hours ago :-)

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you tried with the previous suggestions ?

Comment: The first step is again: to unwind the [uniqueness quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification#Reduction_to_ordinary_existential_and_universal_quantification).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , sorry for such that mistake, I'll try to do it now. thx a lot ^-^

Comment: In natural language, $(\exists ! y) A(y)$ is true iff there is one and only one $y$ such that $A(y)$. Thus it's false if either there is no $y$ such that $A(y)$, or if there are distinct $y1, y2$ satisfying $A$. Here, $A$ is really $A(x, y)$, the entire formula after the two quantifiers involving $P, Q$, and $R$. You should enclose that whole subformula in parentheses, as you've written it, the quantifiers don't bind the variables in $R(x, y)$..

Comment: Hint: If $\forall x~\exists{!}y~S(x,y)$ is false, then there must exist $x$ such that either (1) $\forall y~\neg S(x,y)$ or (2) $\exists y, z~(S(x,y) \land S(x,z) \land y\neq z)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Begin by drilling down into the uniqueness quantifier
$${\neg\forall x~\exists{!}y~S(x,y)\\\neg\forall x~\exists y~(S(x,y)\wedge\forall z~(S(x,z)\to y=z))}$$

Now just apply the usual rules of quantifier duality, and conditional negation.

---

Since the statement to be negated is that: "Every first-term has exactly one second-term which satisfies $S( ,)$", therefore the negation should express that: "There is some first-term with either none or at least two second-terms that satisfy $S(,)~$ (ie *if* there is one such second-term, *then* there is at least another.)."

---

Finally replace $S(x,y)$ with $((P(x,y)\vee \lnot Q(x,y))\leftrightarrow R(x,y))$